# Show summary information of the added employee using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm beginner in PHP MySQL, I would like to ask if this possible:

I have **ADD NEW EMPLOYEE** page after I submit,  I want to have simple summary information of the added employee like

Something like opening a new window page:

**Agent Code:** *The Agent code of the employee newly added* 
**Name:** *Name of the Employee* 
**Type:** *Type of the employee*

Here is PHP Code in my ADD NEW EMPLOYEE page:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
header("Location: index.php");
}
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);



if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
{
$agentCode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['agentCode']);
$pass = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']));
$aFName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['aFName']);
$aLName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['aLName']);
$aMName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['aMName']);
$aSuffixName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['aSuffixName']);
$aContact = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['aContact']);
$aAddress = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['aAddress']);
$aGender = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['aGender']);
$utype = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['utype']);
$loctype = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['loctype']);
$ipadd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ipadd']);


if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO accounts(agentCode, password, agentFname, agentMname, agentLname, aSuffixName, agentContact, agentAddress, agentGender, user_type, location_type, ip_add) 
    VALUES('$agentCode', '$pass', '$aFName', '$aMName', '$aLName', '$aSuffixName', '$aContact', '$aAddress', '$aGender', '$utype', '$loctype', '$ipadd' )"))
{
    ?>

    <script>alert('Successfully added!');</script>

    <?php
  } else {
    ?>
    <script>alert('Agent Code is not available!');</script>
    <?php
   }
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: you want to display previously inserted employees data?

Comment: Get last insert id and do a select.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju Yes sir, the newly added sir.

Comment: do not use `mysql_* ` extension, it's deprecated.

Comment: @6339 how? just change this from `mysql_*` to `mysqli_* ?`

Comment: How about building the summary with the `$_POST` data instead of going back to that database

Comment: @Epodax Yes, I know sir. I try googling first, I can't find any similar topic regarding my question so on how to fetch the data after submit button that's why I'm asking for a tip here.

Comment: @Edmhar check my answer to convert it from mysql_* to mysqli_*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in 2 ways.

1) You will have all posted for db from the form which you used to insert the values to you database. You can use same values to display there.

2) Capture the last insert id, on successfully inserted the data, fetch the data based on that id and display in view.

Comment: `mysql_insert_id());` right sir?

Comment: ya... `$id = mysql_insert_id()`

Comment: how do I get the data from last insert id? I'm getting the last ID I input.

Comment: `mysql_insert_id()` not returning the inserted id??

Comment: It's working but I can fetch the data from by using the `$id = mysql_insert_id()`

Comment: You can or you cant??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92930/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-edmhar).

Answer (score 1):

**`mysql_*`** to **`mysqli_*`**

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$qry  = "INSERT INTO accounts(agentCode, password, agentFname, agentMname, agentLname, aSuffixName, agentContact, agentAddress, agentGender, user_type, location_type, ip_add) 
VALUES('$agentCode', '$pass', '$aFName', '$aMName', '$aLName', '$aSuffixName', '$aContact', '$aAddress', '$aGender', '$utype', '$loctype', '$ipadd' )";

mysqli_query($con, $qry);

// Print auto-generated id
$last_inserted_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
echo "Last Inserted ID: " . $last_inserted_id;

// Now you can perform a select query by using this ID and show
// Agent Code: The Agent code of the employee newly added 
// Name: Name of the Employee 
// Type: Type of the employee 

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Thanks I will use this as my guide for my other page.